# Will my old device reconnect with my account if I change my account password back?

Tags: lock-screens, google-account, locked-out, remote-access

**Background:**

The device in question is an LG Stylo 3 (LS777) which I think is running Nougat. USB debugging is on and it shows up "unauthorized.: I dropped it and broke the screen a couple years ago, and recently fixed it. Either I forgot the pattern screen lock, or (as I've been reading) this phone has whatever bug that causes the device to forget it. I know I can factory reset it, it's just a last option.

**How I got from there to here:**
I had four accounts on this device. Using the hotspot on my current phone, I changed the hotspot wifi name to an open wifi network I know this phone connected to. And voila! Account Action Required notifications pop up!

**Question(s):**
I've been using one account as a guinea pig. I change my passwords regularly, and I don't remember which password I was using when it was on this phone, but I do remember every one I've used with this account.

1. When I get to the right password, will the device authenticate my account and show up again in Find My Device? I'm changing it once every 24 hours and rebooting the phone at random intervals, forcing it to reconnect.
2. Was the option to override the screen lock by remotely locking your device available with Nougat in 2018? (will that plan work)

I'm just curious if I'm wasting my time. Or is there an easier way to bypass or wipe the lock screen that I haven't found yet. The phone is registered to my LG account, but that f'ing site is so convoluted, I haven't seen a way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm on the third pw now. I did it on my laptop, turned on my wifi hotspot, then waited for the prompt to hit my main phone before powering my Stylo 3 on. It connected to the wifi, and all of the notifications started coming. It's still showing up as needing updated.